# How do I know if physical memory module(s) in desktop was changed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios

Is it possible to know if the memory in my desktop was changed and in what date?

For example, where would I check to see when a system admin (or anyone else) went to my desktop and physically added or removed RAM?

Answer (score 2):

If you would run [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/), it will show you module size, manufacturer, part number, date when it manufactured and even **serial number** of RAM module(s) that extracted from RAM's hardware(physical memory module), so if you would keep track of such details then it would be easy to spot such changes.

If you'd like to track serial numbers or RAM modules automatically, you can run via task scheduler (set to run it on windows start) following command and redirect its output to some secret place that only you know:

```
WMIC memorychip get serialnumber
```

If you'd like to track only total amount of installed RAM, you can run:

```
WMIC ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```

`wmic` utility is part of Windows core, so no need in any extra 3rd party software.

Comment: Assuming I just installed it, would it tell me if the ram has changed? Right now it tells me it has 4GB ram.

Comment: @rbhat `hwinfo` wouldn't notify you automatically, it is just a tool that talking directly to various hardware and extracting its internals when you calling it, so if you will write serials and compare them after module changing then you will see difference. Check my updated answer how to check serials automatically

Comment: AFAIR `WMI` comes with any windows since Windows XP

Comment: It seems like a useful tool, but I guess my point is, would this help me in my current situation?

Comment: @rbhat It should help. We doing it with opposite purpose, we tracking PC users instead of admins, because sometimes there're some "smart" persons who trying to do exchange of some hardware. With WMI or hwinfo you can track multiple places, motherboard, RAM, hard drives serial numbers to prevent fraud.

Comment: So I just installed it, How do I know if the amount of RAM has changed in my desktop?

Comment: @rbhat Amount of RAM might be the same, but if you click `memory->Row` you will see internal details I mentioned that will be changed if some1 swap another module. Just write this info somewhere (amount of total RAM, amount of RAM on each module, manufacturer, serial number of module(s) ) and compare it with current setup  when you think some1 replaced module(s)

Comment: How would I know anything changed if I didn't have the app installed _before_ the RAM was changed?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, every modern BIOS keeps track of memory changes.  You would reboot the computer and go into BIOS setup and look for the security or maintenance logs.  The logs would note the change in system RAM.  Now the logs can be cleared, but the log would note that is was cleared with a timestamp.

As for changes to memory in Windows...  I cant think of anything off the top of my head.  It *may* be in the system logs, but its not something I have ever seen before.

Third party management utilities that track hardware would note the memory change, assuming your company uses them.

Comment: One trouble with this method is when a RAM module is replaced with another one of the same size. Few desktop-class BIOSes would log that.